# Serializing Manatee.Json in .NET Core 3

Tags: json, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json, manatee.json

**Background**
I want to provide some JsonSchema from my .NET Core 3 application, as well as other objects serialized into JSON. Since Manatee.Json is frequently updated and provides good support for JsonSchema, they are my preferred choice. At the same time, .NET Core 3 provides excellent support for returning objects with magic that transform them into JSON documents.

Example:

```
public ActionResult<MyFancyClass> MyFancyAction()
{
    return new MyFancyClass {
        Property1 = "property 1 content",
        Property2 = "property 2 content",
    };
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Property1": "property 1 content",
    "Property2": "property 2 content"
}
```

**Problem**
.NET Core 3 has internal support for JSON with its `System.Text.Json` which is used in the previous example. If I try to serialize `Manatee.Json.Schema.JsonSchema`, its internal structure are serialized, not the json schema itself.

Example:

```
public ActionResult<MyFancyClass2> MyFancyAction2()
{
    return new MyFancyClass2 {
        Property1 = "property 1 content",
        Property1Schema = new JsonSchema()
            .Type(JsonSchemaType.String)
    };
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Property1": "property 1 content",
  "Property1Schema": [{
    "name":"type",
    "supportedVersions":15,
    "validationSequence":1,
    "vocabulary": {
      "id":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/vocab/validation",
      "metaSchemaId":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/meta/validation"
    }
  }]
}
```

I expect this:

```
{
  "Property1": "property 1 content",
  "Property1Schema": {
    "type": "string",
  }
}
```

`Manatee.Json.JsonValue` also have a conflicting inner structure, where `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` fails to access internal get methods correctly and I get for instance this exception message:

```
Cannot access value of type Object as type Boolean.
```

**Discovery**
`Manatee.Json.Schema.JsonSchema` has a `.ToJson()` method that can be used to get the correct json schema as a `JsonValue`, but then I get the problem I just mentioned with serializing `Manatee.Json.JsonValue`.

**Question**
Does anyone know a way to enable `System.Text.Json` to serialize `Manatee.Json` structures?

**Sidemark**
*Another way forward is to replace `System.Text.Json` altogether (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59856062/3032543)).*

Answer (score 0):

.NET Core 3 json serialization comes with a lot of configuration options. One of them is to add converters that specify how different types should be serialized. One way forward is to create a `JsonConverter` for `JsonSchema` and another for `JsonValue`.

For `JsonSchema` we can implement a `JsonSchemaConverter` that when serializing/writing, extracts the json schema as a JsonValue and ask the serializer to serialize that JsonValue instead. Like this:

```
public class JsonSchemaConverter : JsonConverter<JsonSchema>
{
    public JsonSchemaConverter()
    {
        _manateeSerializer = new ManateeSerializer();
    }

    private ManateeSerializer _manateeSerializer { get; set; }

    public override JsonSchema Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var jsonText = reader.GetString();
        var jsonValue = JsonValue.Parse(jsonText);
        return _manateeSerializer.Deserialize<JsonSchema>(jsonValue);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonSchema value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var schemaAsJson = value.ToJson(_manateeSerializer);
        try
        {
            System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<JsonValue>(writer, schemaAsJson, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Information($"Failed to serialize JsonSchema ({e.Message});");
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        }
    }
}
```

For `JsonValue` we can change it into something `System.Text.Json` understands, since it is json after all. One unfortunate approach is to serialize the `JsonValue` to a `string`, parsing it with for instance `JsonDocument.Parse(string)` and serialize its `RootElement` property. It feels so unnecessary to go via `JsonDocument`, so if anyone finds a better solution that would be great!
A possible implementation can look like this:

```
public class JsonValueConverter : JsonConverter<JsonValue>
{
    public override JsonValue Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var json = reader.GetString();
        return JsonValue.Parse(json);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string content = value.ToString();
        try
        {
            var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(content);
            JsonSerializer.Serialize<JsonElement>(writer, jsonDocument.RootElement, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Warning($"JsonDocument.Parse(JsonValue) failed in JsonValueConverter.Write(,,).\n{e.Message}");
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        }
    }
}
```

They must be registered at `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonValueConverter());
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonSchemaConverter());
        });
}
```