# Replacing System.Text.Json with Manatee.Json for serialization in .NET Core 3

Tags: json, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json, manatee.json

**Background**
I want to provide some JsonSchema from my .NET Core 3 application, as well as other objects serialized into JSON. Since Manatee.Json is frequently updated and provides good support for JsonSchema, they are my preferred choice. At the same time, .NET Core 3 provides excellent support for returning objects with magic that transform them into JSON documents.

Example:

```
public ActionResult<MyFancyClass> MyFancyAction()
{
    return new MyFancyClass {
        Property1 = "property 1 content",
        Property2 = "property 2 content",
    };
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "Property1": "property 1 content",
    "Property2": "property 2 content"
}
```

**Problem**
.NET Core 3 has internal support for JSON with its `System.Text.Json` which is used in the previous example. If I try to serialize `Manatee.Json.Schema.JsonSchema`, its internal structure are serialized, not the json schema itself.

Example:

```
public ActionResult<MyFancyClass2> MyFancyAction2()
{
    return new MyFancyClass2 {
        Property1 = "property 1 content",
        Property1Schema = new JsonSchema()
            .Type(JsonSchemaType.String)
    };
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Property1": "property 1 content",
  "Property1Schema": [{
    "name":"type",
    "supportedVersions":15,
    "validationSequence":1,
    "vocabulary": {
      "id":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/vocab/validation",
      "metaSchemaId":"https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/meta/validation"
    }
  }]
}
```

I expect this:

```
{
  "Property1": "property 1 content",
  "Property1Schema": {
    "type": "string",
  }
}
```

`Manatee.Json.JsonValue` also have a conflicting inner structure, where `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` fails to access internal get methods correctly and I get for instance this exception message:

```
Cannot access value of type Object as type Boolean.
```

**Discovery**
`Manatee.Json.Schema.JsonSchema` has a `.ToJson()` method that can be used to get the correct json schema as a `JsonValue`, but then I get the problem I just mentioned with serializing `Manatee.Json.JsonValue`.

**Question**
Does anyone know a way to change default serialization in .NET Core 3 from using `System.Text.Json` to using `Manatee.Json`?

**Sidemark**
*Another way forward is to enable `System.Text.Json` to serialize `Manatee.Json` structures (take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59855362/3032543)).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck!  I just release the schema-successor to Manatee.Json: [JsonSchema.Net](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything)!  It has full support of drafts 6 through 2019-09, is based 100% in `System.Text.Json`, and it's ridiculously fast!

Hopefully this helps.

(Don't know why I didn't get emailed for the `Manatee.Json` tag.  Sorry it took so long to find this.)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Up untill now I have been using a ```JsonConverter<JsonValue>``` implementation and a ```JsonConverter<JsonSchema>``` implementation. The ```JsonSchemaConverter``` turns a ```JsonSchema``` into a ```JsonValue```, where upon its converter serializes it into a string, then a ```JsonDocument``` and finally a ```JsonElement```. A long way, but it works :)
I will absolutely try out ```JsonSchema.Net``` =)